# Eutelsat 10B satellite appearance

Tags: communication-satellite, structural-design

Looking at the [SpaceX launch](https://youtu.be/QCpfvj1eiLs?t=3017) of Eutelsat-10B, which was built by Thales Alenia Space, it seemed to have a rather unusual color. Usually geostationary satellites are either covered with a "gold"-like or black-colored foil (multiple layers of a plastic called Kapton, covered with Aluminum on one or two sides). But this one seems "silverish". Is that a new kind of material? Is there any special reason to choose it and not the regular "gold" one?

Comment: [A Spaceflightnow article](https://spaceflightnow.com/2022/11/21/eutelsat-satellite-to-get-last-ride-from-spacexs-oldest-active-falcon-9-booster/) with pre-integration images also shows a silvery satellite.  Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of multi-layer insulation (MLI) used on spacecraft. Gold, aluminum and germanium (the black one) are all used as coatings on Kapton or Mylar sheets, singly or in layers to control the spacecraft's optical thermal properties.  Silver coated Teflon tape is often used on radiator surfaces to dump heat to space radiatively.  Not possible to be sure, but the video looks to be silver coated Kapton.

Comment: It may be possible to be sure, if you find a source.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).